# Spring / JPA join on namespaced key

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am creating a Spring 4 / Spring Data application for an existing database. The database structure and data are defined by a closed source software.

One aspect of the existing system is that you can create a comment on **any** other item in the system. This means, that an article, a document, a media file (all entities in the system) can have any number of comments, and each comment is exactly for one entity in the system. All comments are in the **same** `comment` table.

The way this is implemented is that the table `comment` has a column `comment_for` that holds a concatenated/namespaced/prefixed reference to the actual entity it is a comment for. The current system seems to just builds the join query by prefixing the primary key with the table name:

```
+----+-------------------+----------------+
| id | comment_for       | comment        |
+----+-------------------+----------------+
|   1| article:12345     | This is nice...|
|   2| document:42       | Cool doc!      |
+----+-------------------+----------------+
```

This sample shows two comments, one for an Article with an `article.id` of 12345 and one for a document with `document.id` of 42. I created `@Entities` matching the database tables and the corresponding Repository Interfaces with the query methods I need.

I would like to make use of Spring Data Repositories / Entities to populate the collections of my entities with the corresponding comments, like this (pseudocde) for Entity Article.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "comment_for", prefix = "article:")
private List<Comment> comment = new ArrayList<>();
```

I only need it unidirectional. My entities (at the moment `Article`, `Document` and `Mediafile`) should hold a collection of their comments. I don't need comments to hold a reference back to the entity.

Is there a way to do this? The resulting SQL query should be something like

```
SELECT * FROM .... WHERE comment.comment_for = concat('<entityname>:', <entity>.id);
```

I looked at `@JoinColumn` but I can't modify the used value for the join, only the column name. The only solution I have at the moment are manual `@Query`s on the CommentRepository Interface, which gives me an ArrayList of all comments for a certain Entity / ID combination. But I would like to have the comments automatically joined as part of my Business Entity.

**Update** : It looks like I am able to split the namespace and id from `comment_for` into two new columns without interrupting the existing software. The two columns are now `comment_for_id` and `comment_for_entityname`

Comment: What's the purpose of the key value pair in comment_for? If your entity id matches the value in comment_for exactly it should solve your problem. Can you modify the table? You could also break out comment_for to contain only the id like your entities. Adding an additional column like entity_type would allow you to avoid duplicate id values between different entities.

Comment: I didn't write the Software that created the tables / inserts the data, but they use it to attach / join comments with any other entity. I like the idea of entity_type. How would that work out with Spring. Using @JoinColumns? I have to see if I can use a stored procedure to split the comment_for, as the system that writes the data is not under my control

Comment: You could use @JoinCoumn on the owner side of the relationship between Entity and Comments. It looks like in your case that would be the Comment entity/table, since there are many comments per each entity. That should work, so long as you're able to create a new modified the structure with some PL/SQL. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. If you write an answer post with the corresponding code snippets, I can accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could also break out comment_for to contain only the id like your entities. Adding an additional column like entity_type would allow you to avoid duplicate id values between different entities.

Also you could use @JoinColumn on the owner side of the relationship between Entity and Comments. It looks like in your case that would be the Comment entity/table, since there are many comments per each entity.

Example:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Comments.findAll", query = "select o from Comments o") })
@IdClass(CommentsPK.class)
public class Comments implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4787438687752132432L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "COMMENT_TEXT", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String commentText;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ENTITY_TYPE", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String entityType;
    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMMENT_FOR")
    private EntityDemo entityDemo;
```

Note that I set the combination of all three fields as the primary key, I am not sure what criteria is used as the PK in your current set up.

Here is an example of an Entity. The attributes have been made up for the purpose of demonstration.

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "EntityDemo.findAll", query = "select o from EntityDemo o") })
@Table(name = "ENTITY_DEMO")
public class EntityDemo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8709368847389356776L;
    @Column(length = 1)
    private String data;
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityDemo", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    private List<Comments> commentsList;
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not exactly sure how your mapping works. EntityDemo needs a unidirectional reference to Comments, as there are 14 different EntityDemo entities (Article, Document, Media...). Comment does not know about EntityDEmo on a field level, only as a String-Type maybe.

Comment: Do you capture the different type of entities as an attribute on the EntityDemo object? Or is it realized through inheritance? In regards to Comment having an Entity Demo, perhaps I am not understanding the problem correctly, but my thinking was if you remove the prefix and only contain the id it could be a FK. That FK would point back at the entity that the particular comment is associated with. I know you mentioned this may not be possible since the db structure is managed elsewhere.

Comment: I have updated my question. The foreign key is a composite, made up of the ID and the Entity it from where the ID is. The system that creates the content in the DB uses on single comment table for all comments on any other entity. If I make a comment on an entity Article with ID 123, my post is saved in the table `comment` with `comment_for` set to `article:123`. If I comment on a media file, the comment is in the same comment table but with an `comment_for` set to media_file:123 (123 is now the ID of a mediafile, not a article).